# cakephp2 CakeMail - syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I know this kind of question is a typical newbie error, and I am a newbie.
I'm confused. Everything seems right. Can anyone please help me and point me out where the syntax error is?

Here is what the Stack Trace said

```
CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 362 → CakeEmail->config(string)
        }

        if ($config) {
            $this->config($config);
        } elseif (config('email') && class_exists($this->_configClass)) {

APP\Controller\ContactsController.php line 141 → CakeEmail->__construct(string)
                }

            }



            $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');

            $Email->template('MassMail');
'smtp'
```

And here is how my controller for this page looks like:

```
public function mail() {
        $allCity = $this->City->find('all');
        $this->set('city', $this->City->find('list'));
        $this->set('cityall', $allCity);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $to = [];
            $subject = $this->request->data['Emails']['judul'];
            $content = $this->request->data['Emails']['content'];
            $toList = $this->request->data["Emails"]["to"];
            foreach ($toList as $kota) {
                foreach ($allCity as $cityObj) {
                    if ($kota == $cityObj['City']['kota']) {
                        foreach ($cityObj['Contact']as $kontak) {
                            if ($kontak['email'] != "") {
                                array_push($to, $kontak['email']);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp'); //--> Line 141
            $Email->template('MassMail');
            $Email->emailFormat('html');
            $Email->viewVars(['content' => $content]);
            $Email->from(['info@forkom-jerman.org' => 'Forkom Jerman']);
            $Email->to($to);
            $Email->subject($subject);
            $Email->replyTo('forkom.jerman@gmail.com');
            $Email->transport('smtp');
            if ($Email->send()) {
                $this->Flash->set('Email Telah terkirim');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->set('Email tidak bisa terkirim');
            };

        }
    }
```

And here is my email config:

```
public $smtp = array(
        'log' => true;
        'transport' => 'smpt',
        'from' => 'info@forkom-jerman.org',
        'host' => 'send.one.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'forkom.****@gmail.com',
        'password' => '*****!',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

I have tried changing the **smpt** to **default**, or even leaving it blank so it'll automatically use the default (*$Email = new CakeEmail();*)
I even tried to just copy paste the snippets from cookbook directly that looks like this, just to see how it should be.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
$Email->to('you@example.com');
$Email->subject('About');
$Email->send('My message');
```

But the syntax error message still pointing out to : ***$Email = new CakeEmail();***

I've also tried to clear the cache in tmp>cache>presistent>myapp_cake_core_file_map

But still nothing changed.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, the paste of your stack trace is almost useless because it doesn't really contain the whole information and is terrible formatted. By looking at the code I spotted this and *assume* it's the cause:

```
public $smtp = array(
    'log' => true; // <--- Wrong
    'transport' => 'smpt',
```

It's a semicolon in an array declaration. Fix it and see what happens. If the issue still appears please post *the whole* trace and *properly* formatted.

Also, is there any particular reason why you start learning CakePHP2? It's pretty outdated these days. Go for CakePHP3, even if it is "just" for learning purposes.